# Dagger 2 activity injection not working

Tags: java, android, dependency-injection, dagger-2

I'm trying the new dagger 2, it's my first time implementing it but I can't make it work. I think I got the concept and I understand the example [here](https://github.com/LiveTyping/u2020-mvp)

I try to copy the same structure just a bit modified for my example.

Here is the AppComponent that extends the Graph where I defined the classes I want.

```
@ApplicationScope
@Component(modules = {AppModule.class, DataModule.class})
public interface EFAppComponent extends EFGraph {

    /**
     * An initializer that creates the graph from an application.
     */
    public final static class Initializer {

        private Initializer() {
        } // No instances.

        public static EFAppComponent init(EFApp app) {
            return Dagger_EFAppComponent.builder()
                    .appModule(new AppModule(app))
                    .build();
        }
    }
}


public interface EFGraph {

    public void inject(EFApp app);

    public ImageLoader imageLoader();

    public EventBus eventBus();

}
```

Then inside each module I'm providing the corresponding classes. From here everything works good and Dagger seams to build the Dagger_EFAppComponent correctly.

Then in the Application class I init using the constructor

```
component = EFAppComponent.Initializer.init(this);
component.inject(this);
```

Then my goal is to Inject ImageLoader and EventBus in my activity. To do that I create a ActivityComponent.

```
@ActivityScope
@Component(
        dependencies = EFAppComponent.class,
        modules = ActivityModule.class
)
public interface ActivityComponent {

    public void inject(BaseActivity activity);

}
```

Then from my activity I call inject.

```
activityComponent = Dagger_ActivityComponent.builder()
                .eFAppComponent(component)
                .activityModule(new ActivityModule(this))
                .build();
activityComponent.inject(this);
```

So because I declared @Inject EventBus eventBus in my activity after the inject method call should be injected. Well it's not.

So after debugging and tracking step by step my app and the example I realized that the Dagger_ActivityComponent is not build correctly.

```
private final ActivityModule activityModule;
    private final EFAppComponent eFAppComponent;

    private Dagger_ActivityComponent(Builder builder) {  
        assert builder != null;
        this.activityModule = builder.activityModule;
        this.eFAppComponent = builder.eFAppComponent;
        initialize();
  }
```

Were the initialize method is empty and no Provider are declared as variable.

Am I missing something? I've been the full day trying to make it work but I'm not success.

Appreciate the help.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Well... After the full day spend on this I decide to post it and after 5 minutes I found the solution.

I'm using a BaseActivity for all my activity, and I thought I could use this to inject my components but seams this is not possible.

So I just change this line in my ActivityComponent

```
public void inject(BaseActivity activity)
```

to

```
public void inject(MainActivity activity)
```

So to the name of the activity where I'm injecting the dependencies...

What brings me to a new question. How can I implement a base component to handle all my activities? or I must create a Component for each view/activity/fragment I want to have DI?

Comment: You should create another question I think or modify existing

Comment: I will create a new one so if people face the same problem here is a solution hehe

Comment: Add a second method at the same component `public void inject(SecondActivity activity)`. This is due to static typing which dagger provides.

Comment: Thanks this is useful too.

Comment: FWIW, http://google.github.io/dagger/api/latest/dagger/Component.html now clarifies this point.

Comment: You can inject the `@Inject` annotated dependencies only in the given class that you are currently in. If your `BaseActivity` has `@Inject` annotationed dependencies, those will be injected if you call `inject(baseActivity)`. But you will need to call `inject(mainActivity)` to inject the dependencies specified in `MainActivity`.

Comment: So we just cant inject in the base activity/fragment and forget about it? do we have to inject in every activity?

Comment: You can have a base method that calls inject(activity) but you must declare the method inject(YourActivity activty) in your module.

Answer (score 3):

@Marcel, I recently migrated a project from Dagger 1.2 over to 2.0. I had similar solution where abstract BaseActivity injected the dependencies by doing something along the lines of "application.inject(this);". With Dagger 2.0 this is not possible (as of now) as mentioned in the comment above.

One of the ways I got around this was by changing the "inject" method in the Application class itself to strong type the object. For Example..

```
class MyApp extends Application {
   ...
   public void inject(Object activity) {
    if (activity instanceof MainActivity) {
      mComponent.inject((MainActivity) activity);
    } else if (activity instanceof SubActivity) {
      mComponent.inject((SubActivity) activity);
    }
  }
}
```

With that I did not have to change anything in my existing classes.

FYI: There is a project called [Bullet](https://github.com/tbroyer/bullet) by @thomas-broyer that does this too.

Comment: how to get instance of mComponent