# Dagger 2 Inject Child Class

Tags: java, android, dependency-injection, subclass, dagger-2

I understand that with Dagger 2 I cannot inject in a base class and expect it to carry over to the child class. But why can I not call inject inside of a child class unless I explicitly have an `inject` method for that class?

I tried following the example in this article: [Dagger 2: Even Sharper, Less Square](https://blog.gouline.net/2015/05/04/dagger-2-even-sharper-less-square/). This solution should allow me to call inject in a subclass, but when I test it I get a `NullPointerException` for all of my `@Inject` targets.

```
public abstract class BaseFragment extends Fragment {

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        injectComponent(MyApplication.getComponent());
    }

    protected abstract void injectComponent(AppComponent component);
}

public class MyFragment extends BaseFragment {

    @Inject MyDependency mDependency;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        mDependency.doSomething(); // NullPointerException
        ...
    }

    ...

    @Override
    public void injectComponent(AppComponent component) {
        component.inject(this);
    }
}
```

Is there another way to inject into each subclass without creating an inject method for each an every class? Or is that the only way Dagger 2 will work? If that is the case, I will end up with an absurdly long `Component` class. With an inject method for every `Activity`, `Fragment` or various other helper classes:

```
@Singleton @Component(modules = {AppModule.class})
public interface AppComponent {

    void inject(MyClass clazz);

    void inject(MyClass2 clazz);

    ...

    void inject(MyClassN clazz);
}
```

I would much rather have to call `component.inject()` in every class, than have to do that along with another `inject` method.

---

Although similar, I do not believe my question is a duplicate [Dagger 2 Activity Injection Not Working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29367921/dagger-2-activity-injection-not-working). That question asks why the injection was not working, to which the answer would be: because Dagger 2 has a strong type-association and you must declare an `inject` method for each and every class. This question focuses more on a way around the boilerplate, while hopefully maintaining strong type-association.

Comment: As far as I've understood Dagger2, you're correct in your assumption that it will only work with an inject method for every class in which you want to inject values. The suggested solution, as far as I can tell is to create many scoped components that offer things needed in that particular activity/fragment or part of the app. Hope that helpss

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Dagger 2 activity injection not working](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29367921/dagger-2-activity-injection-not-working)

Comment: @MikaelOhlson That is frustrating, considering I have about thirty fragments at the moment, most of which depend on a `Retrofit` client. Not to mention all of the other dependencies any classes may need.

Comment: Your @Inject annotated fields would need to be present in the base class, anything in the child class won't be seen (I believe this is due to reflection being used for the dagger class generation). You could always just have your component use provisional methods instead of injection methods, like appComponent.getMyDependency(). You could inject the actual component itself into the base class as a protected variable,  and use provisional methods on the component in the child classes. These are just a few options I can think of offhand.

Comment: @ootinii Yeah, I found that out, sadly. As for the provisional methods, I am aware of that as well, but that is a lot of boilerplate that I would like to avoid.

Answer (score 1):

I found a nifty little trick, used in the [AsymmetricFingerprintDialog](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-AsymmetricFingerprintDialog) sample application, though I do not know if I fully understand how it works. The sample uses the first iteration of Dagger, but a quick test showed that it works with Dagger 2 as well.

For each `Fragment` I added an empty constructor with an `@Inject` annotation, then used an `@Inject` annotation to get an instance of the `Fragment` in my `Activity`.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Inject MyFragment mFragment;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        MyApplication.getComponent().inject(this);
        getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction
                .replace(R.id.fragment_container, mFragment).commit();
        ...
    }
}
```

---

```
public class MyFragment extends Fragment {

    @Inject MyDependency mDependency;

    @Inject
    public MyFragment() {}

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        mDependency.doSomething();
        ...
    }
}
```

This allows me to call `MyApplication.getComponent().inject(this)` only in each `Activity`, and the dependencies will be injected to the `Fragment` classes as well. In this way, I only need an `inject` method for each `Activity`, and not each `Fragment`.

```
@Singleton @Component(modules = {AppModule.class})
public interface AppComponent {

    void inject(MainActivity activity);
}
```

I am curious as to how this works though. From what I can see it has nothing to do with Dagger, instead it seems to use the `@Inject` annotation for its intended purpose? Though I am new to Dagger as well as JSR-330, so I am unsure.

---

**Edit:** This method only works with `setRetainInstanceState(true)`, or if you save and restore the instance yourself.

Comment: Be careful since Fragments can be created by Android itself. So in this case injection will not happen

Comment: @EugenMartynov Ah, I did not think of that. You are right, `NullPointerException` on orientation change. I thought that the `Fragment` would get recreated by the `Activity` when it is recreated, I guess that is not the case.